# placement of blocks in hadoop 3

Tags: hadoop3

I am currently concerned with block placement where we are trying to implement our own placement algorithm in Hadoop 3. In Hadoop 2, we can find a file called `PlacementMonitor.java` where we can feed our placement policy but I can't find any such file in the Hadoop 3 source code. Can someone indicate where I can find a file which serves a similarfunctionality?